# Closed cones and exposed faces

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-cone, dual-cone

I was wondering if a closed cone $C$ in a Banach space $X$ of dimension at least two always has an exposed face, that is, a face $F$ such that $F=C\cap\ker\phi$ for some positive $\phi\in X^*\setminus\{0\}$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is a positive functional? $\phi$ is linear....

Comment: $\phi$ is linear, continuous, and $\phi(C)\subseteq [0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find some information on exposed faces and found this problem, so in the category better late then never: The answer is yes, in fact, every element in the boundary lies in an exposed face.

Let $x\in\partial C$. By the Hahn-Banach separation theorem there is a continuous linear functional $\varphi$ and a $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\varphi(x)\leq t<\varphi(y)\qquad y\in C^{\circ}.$$
Now let $y\in C^{\circ}$. Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\varphi(\frac{1}{n}y)=0$ so $t\leq0$. Furthermore suppose that $\varphi(y)<0$, then for $n$ large enough $\varphi(ny)<t\leq0$, which is a contradiction, so $\varphi$ is a positive linear functional.

From this it follows that $\emptyset\neq F=\text{ker}(\varphi)\cap C\subset\partial C$. Finally let $x,y\in C$ such that $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in F$, then $\varphi(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=0$ and as $\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\geq0$ we find that $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)=0$, so $F$ is a face.

Comment: @ Floris Claassens. Thank you for your response! Yes, I understand why this would be true in case the cone in question has an interior. However, in general it is unclear to me why such an exposed face would exist.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi \in X^*$ is positive, then $C \cap \ker(\phi)$ is automatically a face, which is furthermore exposed.¹ It is proper if and only if $\phi \neq 0$. So the question is: are there non-trivial positive functionals? This is answered by basic duality: since $C$ is closed and convex, it it also weakly closed (see e.g. [1, Thm 3.12], [2, IV.3.1], or [3, Thm 8.9(1)]). Then, under the dual pair $\langle X,X^*\rangle$, we know that $C$ is equal to its double dual wedge $C^{**}$ (by the one-sided bipolar theorem [2, Thm IV.1.5] or the wedge duality theorem [3, Thm 2.13(3)]). So $C^* = \{0\}$ if and only if $C = X$. We conclude: a closed wedge $C \subseteq X$ has a non-trivial exposed face if and only if $C \neq X$.

<sub>¹: Most authors include $C$ and $\varnothing$ among the exposed faces, so $C \cap \ker(0)$ is also an exposed face.</sub>

**References.**

[1]: Walter Rudin, *Functional Analysis*, Second Edition (1991), McGraw–Hill.

[2]: H.H. Schaefer, with M.P. Wolff, *Topological Vector Spaces*, Second Edition (1999), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 3, Springer.

[3]: Charalambos D. Aliprantis, Rabee Tourky, *Cones and Duality* (2007), Graduate Studies in Mathematics 84, American Mathematical Society.